# Como fazer uma máscara de texto pra uma checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Tentei pesquisar e não achei uma forma de fazer uma máscara pra texto de um checkbox (no meu caso está nomeado como `ativo`)

```
 <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th class="idcontra">ID.Contrato</th>
              <th>Num.Contrato</th>
              <th>Data Inicio</th>
              <th>Data Final</th>
              <th>Responsável</th>
              <th>Cliente/Fornecedor</th>
              <th>Ativo</th>
              <th>...</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php

          while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
          {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$user_data['ativo']."</td>";
            echo "<td>
            
              <a href='cadastroContrato.php?idContrato=$user_data[idContrato]'><button class = 'azul'>Editar</button></a>
            <a href='delete.php?idContrato=$user_data[idContrato]'><button class = 'azul'>Deletar</button></a>
            <a href='../cadastroItem/index.php?idContrato=$user_data[idContrato]'><button class = 'azul'>Itens Contratro</button></a>
            
              </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
          }
        ?>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Formulário:

````
form action="contrato.php" id='cadastroRegistro' method = "POST">
     
              
            <div class="form-check form-switch col-1">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" name= 'ativo' id='ativo' value="on">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Ativo:</label>
            </div>
          </div>


```
````

Answer (score 0):

Bom galera consegui fazer uma máscara usando o próprio PHP, forma bem simples forém funcional.

```
 $user_data['ativo'] == 1 ? 'Ativo' : 'Inativo';
```